# Passing irregular xml file to the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a sample xml as follows. I am trying to get all or specific data and then insert into the my sql table which has the same columns representing the values coming from xml. I looked through some solutions but the xml files are not formatted like I have in here. Can you help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?> 
<VehicleStatusResponse xmlns:ns2= 
  "http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position" xmlns="http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/status"> 
<VehicleStatus> 
       <VIN>VF254ANA735752628</VIN> 
       <TriggerType>TIMER</TriggerType> 
       <CreatedDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:20</CreatedDateTime> 
       <ReceivedDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:57</ReceivedDateTime> 
       <GNSSPosition> 
              <ns2:Latitude>49.18557</ns2:Latitude> 
              <ns2:Longitude>11.18557</ns2:Longitude> 
              <ns2:Heading>33</ns2:Heading> 
              <ns2:Altitude>500</ns2:Altitude> 
              <ns2:Speed>16.4</ns2:Speed> 
              <ns2:PositionDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:20</ns2:PositionDateTime> 
       </GNSSPosition> 
       <WheelBasedSpeed>16.07</WheelBasedSpeed> 
       <TachographSpeed>15.83</TachographSpeed> 
       <HRTotalVehicleDistance>817.5</HRTotalVehicleDistance> 
       <EngineTotalFuelUsed>575</EngineTotalFuelUsed> 
       <FuelLevel1>83</FuelLevel1> 
       <CatalystFuelLevel>88.48</CatalystFuelLevel> 
       <GrossCombinationVehicleWeight>10000</GrossCombinationVehicleWeight> 
</VehicleStatus> 
</VehicleStatusResponse>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products' stored procedures are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2016 @jarlh

Comment: The XML above is missing the final closing tag `</VehicleStatusResponse>`. Please clearify what actual problem you have...

Comment: Thanks, I changed it @Shnugo. The problem is how can I get the properties from the xml file and then insert into the my table?

Comment: If the XML above is a *real-word-example* there's nothing irregular...

Comment: As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get your value into a declare variable of type `XML` or into an XML-typed data table column. As your XML contains namespaces you have to declare them in a `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` first. You might use wildcard syntax (`*:`), but its better to be as specific as possible.

The `.nodes()` call navigates to the Level of `<VehicleStatus>`. All elements below are simply `1:1` and easy to read...

You can try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<VehicleStatusResponse xmlns:ns2= 
  "http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position" xmlns="http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/status"> 
<VehicleStatus> 
       <VIN>VF254ANA735752628</VIN> 
       <TriggerType>TIMER</TriggerType> 
       <CreatedDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:20</CreatedDateTime> 
       <ReceivedDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:57</ReceivedDateTime> 
       <GNSSPosition> 
              <ns2:Latitude>49.18557</ns2:Latitude> 
              <ns2:Longitude>11.18557</ns2:Longitude> 
              <ns2:Heading>33</ns2:Heading> 
              <ns2:Altitude>500</ns2:Altitude> 
              <ns2:Speed>16.4</ns2:Speed> 
              <ns2:PositionDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:20</ns2:PositionDateTime> 
       </GNSSPosition> 
       <WheelBasedSpeed>16.07</WheelBasedSpeed> 
       <TachographSpeed>15.83</TachographSpeed> 
       <HRTotalVehicleDistance>817.5</HRTotalVehicleDistance> 
       <EngineTotalFuelUsed>575</EngineTotalFuelUsed> 
       <FuelLevel1>83</FuelLevel1> 
       <CatalystFuelLevel>88.48</CatalystFuelLevel> 
       <GrossCombinationVehicleWeight>10000</GrossCombinationVehicleWeight> 
</VehicleStatus> 
</VehicleStatusResponse>';
```

--This is the query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/status'
                          ,'http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position' AS ns2)
SELECT vs.value('VIN[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS VehicleStatus_VIN
      ,vs.value('TriggerType[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS VehicleStatus_TriggerType
      ,vs.value('CreatedDateTime[1]','datetime') AS VehicleStatus_CreatedDateTime
      ,vs.value('ReceivedDateTime[1]','datetime') AS VehicleStatus_ReceivedDateTime
      ,vs.value('(GNSSPosition/ns2:Latitude)[1]','decimal(14,6)') AS VehicleStatus_GNSSPosition_Latitude
      ,vs.value('(GNSSPosition/ns2:Longitude)[1]','decimal(14,6)') AS VehicleStatus_GNSSPosition_Longitude
      /*other columns follow the same pattern*/
FROM @xml.nodes('/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus') AS A(vs)
```

### update: insert into a table

Easiest was to wrap this call as CTE like

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(...)
,DerivedTableCTE AS
(
   The query here
)
INSERT INTO YourTable (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM DerivedTableCTE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XML type and XML methods if you remove or modify the declaration.  The SQL Server XML type only supports UCS-2 encoding and doesn't recognize "standalone". The example below uses string manipulation to tweak the declaration. You'll need to change the data types according to your actual column types and should specify an explicit column list on the `INSERT` statement. I omitted that in this example only because I didn't want to assume your actual table columns matched the element names in the XML.

```
DECLARE @xml xml;
DECLARE @xmlString nvarchar(MAX) = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?> 
<VehicleStatusResponse xmlns:ns2= 
  "http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position" xmlns="http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/status"> 
<VehicleStatus> 
       <VIN>VF254ANA735752628</VIN> 
       <TriggerType>TIMER</TriggerType> 
       <CreatedDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:20</CreatedDateTime> 
       <ReceivedDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:57</ReceivedDateTime> 
       <GNSSPosition> 
              <ns2:Latitude>49.18557</ns2:Latitude> 
              <ns2:Longitude>11.18557</ns2:Longitude> 
              <ns2:Heading>33</ns2:Heading> 
              <ns2:Altitude>500</ns2:Altitude> 
              <ns2:Speed>16.4</ns2:Speed> 
              <ns2:PositionDateTime>2014-09-08T09:30:20</ns2:PositionDateTime> 
       </GNSSPosition> 
       <WheelBasedSpeed>16.07</WheelBasedSpeed> 
       <TachographSpeed>15.83</TachographSpeed> 
       <HRTotalVehicleDistance>817.5</HRTotalVehicleDistance> 
       <EngineTotalFuelUsed>575</EngineTotalFuelUsed> 
       <FuelLevel1>83</FuelLevel1> 
       <CatalystFuelLevel>88.48</CatalystFuelLevel> 
       <GrossCombinationVehicleWeight>10000</GrossCombinationVehicleWeight> 
</VehicleStatus> 
</VehicleStatusResponse>';

SET @xmlString = REPLACE(@xmlString, 'encoding="UTF-8"', 'encoding="UCS-2"');
SET @xmlString = REPLACE(@xmlString, 'standalone="true"', '');
SET @xml = @xmlString;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
      DEFAULT 'http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/status'
    ,'http://fms-standard.com/rfms/v1.0.0/xsd/common/position' AS ns2
    )
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
    SELECT
          @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/VIN)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/TriggerType)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/CreatedDateTime)[1]', 'datetime2(3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/ReceivedDateTime)[1]', 'datetime2(3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GNSSPosition/ns2:Latitude)[1]', 'decimal(8,5)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GNSSPosition/ns2:Longitude)[1]', 'decimal(8,5)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GNSSPosition/ns2:Heading)[1]', 'int')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GNSSPosition/ns2:Altitude)[1]', 'int')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GNSSPosition/ns2:Speed)[1]', 'decimal(8,3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GNSSPosition/ns2:PositionDateTime)[1]', 'datetime2(3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/WheelBasedSpeed)[1]', 'decimal(8,3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/TachographSpeed)[1]', 'decimal(8,3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/HRTotalVehicleDistance)[1]', 'decimal(8,3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/EngineTotalFuelUsed)[1]', 'int')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/CatalystFuelLevel)[1]', 'decimal(8,3)')
        , @xml.value('(/VehicleStatusResponse/VehicleStatus/GrossCombinationVehicleWeight)[1]', 'int');
```

Comment: If there's only one XML this will make no difference, but in general I'd suggest to use `.nodes()` first to navigate to the target level and use values on a shorter `XPath`. Your query will call `.value()` over and over...

Comment: Sorry for being picky, but I would always avoid to use such an insert without a column list.

Comment: @Shnugo, I completely agree an explicit column list is a best practice.  I omitted it only because the question didn't include the target table DDL and I didn't want to assume the column and element names were the same. I'll add that to my answer.